# assembler how does the jump if above works

Tags: assembly, x86, x87

We are comparing two values 
 `1` and `pi`

then i use 'jump if above' or jump if greater:

we have:

```
1 - pi < 0
```

so we don't jump.

it only occurs when condition  :

`x - value > 0` is true, right ?
and how does the overflow flag work in jg ?

```
fcomp ; st0:1 , st1:pi

 fstsw ax   
 sahf 

ja nie_odejmuj ;
```

Do we jump ?

using FPU

Comment: Please specify architecture, platform and exact comparing method. E.g. for x86: old-styled FCOM with setting C0-C3 and manual copying of flags? Newer FCOMI family with direct setting of bits in Flags? SSE comparing? Something another?

Comment: @Netch: `fcomi` and modern `comiss`/`sd` all set FLAGS the same way as legacy x87 `fstsw ax`/`sahf`.  That's not a coincidence, clearly they were designed that way.  (Probably for easy porting/adoption and because CF is more useful than `OF!=SF`).  [Why do x86 FP compares set CF like unsigned integers, instead of using signed conditions?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57188286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ja` needs CF==0 and ZF==0. It doesn't check OF. In x87 flags this means C0==0 and C3==0. It's exactly condition that ST(0) > ST(1) for the comparing using `FCOM`, `FCOMP`, etc.

You shouldn't be confused with formal condition difference (as `ja` is for comparing unsigned numbers) because x87 condition flags differ and are passed here using special transport. It could be even possible to see absolutely mismatching conditions, but Intel tried to provide at least far similarity between conditions and checking instructions.

OTOH, `jg`, yes, checks very other conditions with bits that aren't passed using `fstsw`+`sahf`. So it isn't applicable here even if is named the same as needed condition.

This is legacy issue, as well as tons of other x86 strange solutions. (30+ years of developing without redesign from scratch doesn't give a consistent result. OTOH, all they are well documented so you should just follow the known recipes.)

UPDATE: btw, you can alternatively skip `sahf` and check the flags directly:

```
fstsw ax
test ax, 4100h
jz nie_odejmuj
```

It is longer in code but expresses the method more clearly.

Comment: Also more efficient because `test/je` can macro-fuse into a single compare-and-branch uop on modern x86, while still being compatible with pre-PPro (not using `fcomi`).  Although at this point PPro `fcomi` / `cmov` are pretty much baseline even for 32-bit code, and SSE/SSE2 is more most 32-bit code.  So that's more like a fun fact than useful optimization+compatibility advice.